# Parsing XML with Javascript and create array

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I am stepping through a bunch of XML, trying to build an array within javascript.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf8" ?>
<session>
    <id>12</id>
    <name>20130520105033-0-1</name>
    <userid>0</userid>
    <changed>2013-05-20 11:16:31</changed>
    <till>1</till>
    <custid>1</custid>
    <details>
        <item>
            <prodcode>TRD3066</prodcode>
            <qty>1</qty>
            <tax>15</tax>
            <uprice>23.1</uprice>
            <price>1</price>
        </item>
        <item>
            <prodcode>DIC72000280</prodcode>
            <qty>1</qty>
            <tax>15</tax>
            <uprice>278.26</uprice>
            <price>1</price></item>
        <item>
            <prodcode>KRE22208</prodcode>
            <qty>1</qty>
            <tax>15</tax>
            <uprice>4.65</uprice>
            <price>1</price>
        </item>
    </details>
    <comment></comment>
    <customer_comment></customer_comment>
</session>
```

Javascript used to parse this:
(after passing the details xml tag)

```
function parse(details){
    var ret=[];var tot=[];
    jQuery(details).find("item").each(function(){
        ret[0]= jQuery(this).find('prodcode').text();
        console.log("parse "+ret[0]);
        ret[1]= jQuery(this).find('qty').text();
        ret[2]= jQuery(this).find('tax').text();
        ret[3]= jQuery(this).find('uprice').text();
        ret[4]= jQuery(this).find('price').text();
        tot.push(ret);
        console.log("tot="+tot);
    });
    return tot;
}
```

The problem console result is

parse TRD3066 
tot=TRD3066,1,15,23.1,1 
parse DIC72000280 
tot=DIC72000280,1,15,278.26,1,DIC72000280,1,15,278.26,1 
parse KRE22208 
tot=KRE22208,1,15,4.65,1,KRE22208,1,15,4.65,1,KRE22208,1,15,4.65,1

It's one of those nights, and I am just not seeing why the end tot array is not all the individual items ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is the `.each` function that is causing the issue, you should replace it with simple `for` loop

```
var items = jQuery(details).find("item");
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var ret = [];
    ret[0] = jQuery(items[i]).find('prodcode').text();
    console.log("parse " + ret[0]);
    ret[1] = jQuery(items[i]).find('qty').text();
    ret[2] = jQuery(items[i]).find('tax').text();
    ret[3] = jQuery(items[i]).find('uprice').text();
    ret[4] = jQuery(items[i]).find('price').text();
    tot.push(ret);
    console.log("tot=" + tot);
}
```

Comment: missing the i in the middle of the for loop...
but still same results! Any other ideas?

Comment: Sorry, missed a couple of lines. Please check again

Comment: That's it. the var ret = []; clearing the ret array next time around, and working with the index of items. Thanks UmairP!

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing a reference to the same ret array multiple times to tot, then changing the referenced ret array.

Also note that tot.push(ret) does not push each item from ret onto tot, rather it pushes a reference to ret to tot. When you change the contents of ret in the next round, it will look like every item in tot is changing, because they are all references to the same array.

Perhaps instead of tot.push(ret) you want to

```
tot.push(ret[0], ret[1], ret[2], ret[3], ret[4]);
```

Or don't make that ret array at all and instead just push individual texts as you get them.